# Can I get the list of tests created with cypress?

Tags: angular, mocha.js, chai, e2e-testing, cypress

I would like to get/extract all test name (decribe and it) but I can't figure out how to do it. I use cypress with angular.

Comment: did u figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so via the terminal with this command. Execute it in the directory of your tests:

```js
grep -hr "describe(\| it(" *
```

It will grep all `describe(` and `it(` in the files and display it.
By using option -h it won't show the filename. 
By using option -r it will search recursive, searching trough all directories and files below the point of execution.
I search for `it(` (with the space) for a reason. I assume you are using indention in the code, so it will exist. Besides that, by adding the space you rule out other commands that end with it (for example 'wait' and visit).

Answer (score 2):

I took @Mr. J.'s solution a little farther and formatted the output to be only whitespaced ordered plain text with two passes of `sed`:

```
grep -hr "describe(\| it(" * | sed -E "s/( *)describe\(['\`\"](.*)['\`\"],.*/\n\1\2/g" | sed -E "s/( *)it\(['\`\"](.*)['\`\"],.*/\1\2/g"
```

which yields a decent outline depending on the exact whitespacing in your test files where describes have newline before them. Mine look something like:

```
Interacting with the page buttons and inputs while signing up
        should allow you to modify the signup options

        baz section
            allows you to toggle between foo selection and bar ones
                selecting that bar populates the relevant baz
```